# 2 workflows vs Process builder. Which one is better?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, field-update, email-alert

I want to design a workflow to make it work like,

> If criteria C1 =true; -> Action 1. Field Update
>
> If criteria C1 & C2=true -> Action 1. Field Update 2. Email alert.

In a single workflow I'm not able to implement this one, also I don't want to use process builder(least priority) here. Neither want to go for trigger.
Instead want to keep 2 workflows W1 & W2.

> W1 :  C1= true; -> 1. Field Update
>
> W2 : C1 & C2 =true -> 1. Field Update & 2. Email ALert.

Is this a good design practice? Or should I go by process builder? Please suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should go with Process Builder. The beauty of process builder is one process can handle multiple criteria updates and all of them will be in a single process like the one you have now.

**Process Builder is the future!**  If you see the new Professional Salesforce Editions, they don't have workflows anymore, they only come with Process Builder.  Process Builder can do a lot more than what a workflow does. You shouldn't be surprised if Salesforce stops allowing creation of new workflows 2-3 years down the line.

When a single process builder can handle both the scenarios, you should go with it instead of multiple workflows. And process builder can also help you you set the execution order for your 2 criteria unlike the 2 workflow rules here.

**EDIT:**

In your first criteria in the process builder, if you click on STOP, there is an option to **continue evaluating next criteria**. So, even if the 2nd criteria falls under the "false" of 1st criteria, the process continues on to the next criteria and evaluates and runs it too, all with in a transaction.

Comment: Completely agree with sfdc's comments, Process Builder is being developed to replace Workflow Rules (& then do more than WFRs). The one risk with the PB at the moment is that if you set your criteria to evaluate a field that's empty, this will throw an error whereas a WFR will just evaluate to false.

Comment: Using the PB also helps avoid limits - you're [limited](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits.htm&language=en_US) to [300](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Increasing-Maximum-Number-of-Workflow-Rules-Per-Entity&language=en_US) rules & processes per object. You can evaluate up to 2,000 criteria nodes (& trigger multiple resulting actions for each) for a process, versus the 300 WFRs.

Comment: If limits are a concern, take a look at [this](https://salesforcesidekick.com/2016/05/09/building-your-process-builder-for-optimum-performance-and-bulkification/) guide on writing criteria to avoid wasting resources too.

Comment: Thanks both of you,  but  i think this particular scenario is not achievable by either PB also... can you please help me how I can use PB in this scenario???

Comment: At the end of the first Condition block (criteria), there will be a STOP Button.  Click on stop button and choose "Continue Evaluting Next Criteria too".  That should help

Comment: Thanks @sfdcFanBoy , I'm implementing the same and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcFanBoy , it is working...is it a new feature in summer 16?

Comment: Yes it is......,